# Casting pointer from one base type to another

Tags: c++, pointers

-EDIT-

Thanks for the quick response, I'd been having really weird problems with my code and I changed my casts to dynamic_cast and its working perfectly now

-ORIGINAL POST-

Is it safe to cast a pointer of one base class to another base class? To expand on this a bit, will the pointer I've marked in the following code not result in any undefined behavior?

```
class Base1
{
public:
   // Functions Here
};


class Base2
{
public:
   // Some other Functions here
};

class Derived: public Base1, public Base2
{
public:
  // Functions
};

int main()
{
  Base1* pointer1 = new Derived();
  Base2* pointer2 = (Base2*)pointer1; // Will using this pointer result in any undefined behavior?
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should use a `dynamic_cast`, not a C-style cast.

Comment: Oh, is `Base2` inherited private, or is that a transcription mishap? If it's private, my answer is not correct!

Comment: its supposed to be inherited public, I typed it wrong

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Will using this pointer result in any undefined behavior?

Yes. The C-style cast will only try the following casts:

- `const_cast`
- `static_cast`
- `static_cast`, then `const_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`, then `const_cast`

It will use `reinterpret_cast` and do the wrong thing.

If `Base2` is polymorphic, i.e, has `virtual` functions, the correct cast here is `dynamic_cast`.

```
Base2* pointer2 = dynamic_cast<Base2*>(pointer1);
```

If it doesn't have virtual functions, you can't do this cast directly, and need to cast down to `Derived` first.

```
Base2* pointer2 = static_cast<Derived*>(pointer1);
```

Comment: Is `Base1` polymorphic though? Can it be changed to `Base2`?

Comment: +1 But still trying to figure out what difference would it make for static_cast vs dynamic_cast in this scenario even with the presence of virtual functions.

Comment: @Mahesh `dynamic_cast` requires the classes to be polymorphic (in other words have a virtual method).

Comment: @Mahesh consider another type `struct Derived2 : Base2, Base1 {};`. On an object of this type, a conversion from `Base1` to `Base2` is different than on the type on the question: the pointer adjustments needed are different. Given a `Base1*` the compiler has no information to decide what adjustments are correct. So, it needs either: RTTI, which is what `dynamic_cast` uses (basically, a vptr), or you tell it explicitly what type it's dealing with.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes suppose `Base1` and `Base2` both are polymorphic but still cast `Base2* pointer2 = dynamic_cast<Base2*>(pointer1);` shouldn't work, should they? since `Base1` and `Base2` both ain't directly related in this case

Comment: @Mr.Anubis yes, it works, because the underlying object is both types. `dynamic_cast` will use RTTI to find out it's a `Derived`, and work from there to do the cast. It's called a cross-cast, because it casts across two different hierarchies. It's not common.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes see this please : http://ideone.com/CAuS3 , I'm confused now 0o

Comment: There's no problem there. `main` returns 1, which indicates an error. Change it to return 0 to indicate success :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes see this code please : http://ideone.com/dIhwo , here `base2` type (destination ptr type in cast)  is not polymorphic but still program runs fine. can you please explain me rules precise or where I can find them ? Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dynamic_cast` operator. This function returns null if types are incompatible.